# Не пингуются хосты в Интернете из гостевой ОС VMWare

Tags: vmware

Есть компьютер с ОС Windows 7 Ultimate, 32-bit  (Build 7600) 6.1.7600. У него статический IP. На компьютере установлена VMware Workstation 9.0.0 build-812388. Там создана виртуальная машина Win XP.Брандмауэр отключен для всех случаев.

**Случай 1**:В VMWare используется NAT (VMnet8). Win7 и WinXP пингуются. Интернет на гостевой ОС (WinXP) присутствует. Вроде бы все хорошо, но хосты в интернете не пингуются из WinXP: Дестинейшн хост анричбл. Подчскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

**Случай 2**:Для подключения WinXP используется тип адаптера Host-Only (создана сеть VMnet2). DHCP не используется.

```
Win7:IP: 191.168.137.1 
NetMask:255.255.255.0 

WinXP:IP: 191.168.137.2 
NetMask:255.255.255.0 
GateWay:191.168.137.1
```

Между собой Win7 и WinXP пингуются. Интернета на WinXP нет. Компьютеры в интернете не пингуются. На Win7 интернет расшарен (основной адаптер -> свойства -> доступ -> "Разрешить другим ...", "Подключ к сети: VMnet2", "Разрешить другим пользователям управление...").

**Вопрос**: Как в первом случае сделать, чтобы пинговались хосты вне локальной сети (VMnet8)?Как сделать, чтобы на WinXP был И-нет (может я что-то не правильно сделал)? Пробовал использовать в качестве гостевой ОС UbuntuServer - ситуация аналогична. Пробовал использовать 8 версию VMWare - ситуация аналогична.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать не NAT или Host-only, а сетевой мост.

Answer (score 1):

При использовании режима Host-only не будет связи с внешним миром.

Для режима NAT не надо выставлять шаринг сетевой, главное чтобы Gateway и DNS был прописан в WinXP.Что дает команда tracert mail.ru на машине с WinXP в режиме NAT?

Answer (score 0):

Случай 1. Для прохождение пингов, необходимо доделать NAT. На хосте подключение по локальной сети расшариваем для VMnet8. В настройках виртуалки указываем шлюз.

Случай 2. Случай 2:Для подключения WinXP используется тип адаптера Host-Only (создана сеть VMnet2). DHCP не используется.
Win7:IP: 191.168.137.1NetMask: 255.255.255.0, как я понял интернет должен быть через нее (Где gateway и Nameserver DNS?)
WinXP:IP: 191.168.137.2NetMask: 255.255.255.0GateWay: 191.168.137.1
Получается на Win7 интернета нет, а на WinXP интернет должен быть, такого с Host-only быть не может